# Windows 10 / Linux dualboot on GPT-table without (!) UEFI - maybe another approach possible?

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub, bootloader, gpt

Would the following sequence work to run Windows on a `GPT` partition table without (!) using `UEFI`-boot?

1. Install Windows the classic way in `Legacy-BIOS` mode onto a usual `MSDOS` type partition table
2. Boot into a live-system containing *Clonezilla*
3. Create an image of the successfully installed Windows-version using *Clonezilla*
4. Reset the whole drive and format it as `GPT` (still in `Legacy-BIOS`)
5. Restore the Windows-image to the target partition using *Clonezilla*
6. Reboot and install any Linux-distribution of your choice to a different partition
7. Configure the `GRUB`-bootloader to detect the Windows-bootloader on its partition
8. Maybe Windows can be booted by `GRUB` now?

---

As I said, this is just an idea and won't work probably. Nevertheless I would love to hear your opinion about it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Windows doesn't support booting from `Legacy-BIOS` and booting from a GPT partitioned disk. You either need to keep the whole thing as UEFI/GPT or Legacy/MBR if you want to boot Windows.

Comment: Why do you want to use GPT in legacy mode?  UEFI is supported by virtually all distributions, secure boot is an optional feature of UEFI, so I doubt it has anything to do with that.  GRUB has supported UEFI for a decade now.

Comment: Well, `legacy-bios` is way more "straight ahead" and less vulnerable to attackers than `UEFI` I thought?